# How to set multiple object values when using Immutable JS map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am new to redux, Is this correct way of doing redux in following code, please?
This is a reducer method when action called to execute currentTime.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { UPDATE_TIME } from './actions';
import { Map } from 'immutable';

 const initialState = Map({update:false, currentTime: ""});

 function currentTime(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_TIME:
      return {...state, update: true, currentTime: action.time };
    default:
      return state;
  }
} 

const currentTimeReducer = combineReducers({
    currentTime
});

export default currentTimeReducer
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it

1. You can set the value using **[`set()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/set)** function

   ```
     case UPDATE_TIME:
        state = state.set('update', true);
        return state.set('currentTime', action.time);
   ```

   or even

   ```
    case UPDATE_TIME:
        return state.set('update', true)
                    .set('currentTime', action.time);
   ```

However this is not feasible when you have multiple changes

2. The other option is **[`merge()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/merge)**

   ```
   case UPDATE_TIME:
      return state.merge({update: true, currentTime: action.time})
   ```

However in case of a nested state update you would need to do a deepMerge. See the details of **[`mergeDeep`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mergeDeep)**

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, is there any chance could do it by reselect on state?

Comment: What do you mean by `reselect on state`

Comment: From what I understand, reselect is for having memoizable selectors,I am not sure, if it will be used to update the Immutable states in redux store

Answer (score 0):

We use immutable JS to create new instance on each small change in the existing object. Immutable JS MAP has a `set` method to set attribute and return new instance of the object. 
[Here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map)  you can find api doc for MAP

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import { UPDATE_TIME } from './actions';
    import { Map } from 'immutable';

     const initialState = Map({update:false, currentTime: ""});

     function currentTime(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_TIME:
            let newState = state;
            newState = newState.set('update', true );
            newState = newState.set('currentTime', action.time);
            return newState;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    } 

    const currentTimeReducer = combineReducers({
        currentTime
    });

    export default currentTimeReducer
```

Look best practices in [this](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html#immutable-js-best-practices) doc